# Intel NUC wont power on, thinking of changing the CMOS battery anything else to consider?

Tags: bios, motherboard, power-supply, battery

Ive got an Intel Nuc PC, which is flashed with a linux OS and is running some custom software to be an automation controller.

The idea is that automation controller is always on and has been running since c. 2016.

In the past when there where power cuts etc the NUC would recover once the power was back on. But today when there has been a power cut the NUC has not come back online. Ive tried to manually power it up via the power button on the front but to no avail.

Reading on the Intel website [HERE](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/support/articles/000006787/intel-nuc.html) there is a CMOS battery on board which last 3 years when not connected to power, but presumably significantly longer if connected to power.

My questions are as follows :

a) Im not sure if the CMOS has gone and my first port of call is to replace that, but wondered if there is anything else i should be looking at, at the same time ?

b) Finally if i change the CMOS battery will the NUC lose its firmware, OS and other files ?

My other thought was PSU, but there is no reason for a PSU to fail and not come back to life during a power cut (the PSU is wired to a surge protected PDU).

Comment: _"will the NUC lose its firmware, OS and other files ?"_ - the article you've linked clearly states the effects of the battery failing. (and the list doesn't include the device not booting)

Comment: A failed CMOS battery doesn't usually mean the device fails to power on. You would still get it power on and a warning would come up saying the CMOS battery needs replacing so the internal clock can stay up-to-date. If the device does not power on (no lights anywhere) then you're likely looking at a problem with the power connector on the nuc or the power supply that plugs into the wall.,

Comment: Also this is unrelated but worth adding. Isn't an Intel NUC a bit overkill to serve as a mere automation controller? Those things are like 700+ bucks each and if all you want it for is an automation controller I'm sure you can achieve that with a Raspberry Pi

Comment: Have you tried removing *all* power, leaving it off for ~20 minutes, and rebooting? If that does not work, it could be that the power issue was a bit more than outage, i.e., there could have been high-voltage transients that fried the power supply and/or NUC. Test the NUC with another PS.

Comment: @Mastaxx Thin clients are also great for such applications. They use relatively little power while being reasonably powerful. They are x86, so slightly more flexible than ARM, and oftentimes have SATA ports. Some offer PCIe over M.2 or even through proper PCIe slots. And the best part is they aren't terribly overpriced due to component shortages, as opposed to Raspberry Pis.

Comment: @gronostaj i agree, but when reading on forums online some people who were reporting similar issues said if they changed the CMOS they got the NUC working again so that was my next port of call

Comment: Actually, I have a NUC that won't power on until I disconnect the CMOS battery and re-connect it, and from what I've found online, I'm not alone, there are other people reporting the same problem. I still need to replace the battery to see if the problem goes away.